# How do I write scripts to the page with jQuery when inside a script already

Tags: jquery, include, append

I'm building a web page form with jquery append() , html() etc and I'm at the point where I have to write the script shown below to the page ( which gets called by some other external include script by ID I think)

What's the best way to write this script to the page or include it so the external calling script can find it?

Related question:

Do I have to strip all the whitespace out if I use jquery html() or similar method?  I always seem to run into trouble with whitespace when outputting large chunks of formatted stuff to page..  thanks

```
<script id="template-upload" type="text/x-jquery-tmpl">
    <tr class="template-upload{{if error}} ui-state-error{{/if}}">
        <td class="preview"></td>
        <td class="name">${name}</td>
        <td class="size">${sizef}</td>
        {{if error}}
            <td class="error" colspan="2">Error:
                {{if error === 'maxFileSize'}}File is too big
                {{else error === 'minFileSize'}}File is too small
                {{else error === 'acceptFileTypes'}}Filetype not allowed
                {{else error === 'maxNumberOfFiles'}}Max number of files exceeded
                {{else}}${error}
                {{/if}}
            </td>
        {{else}}
            <td class="progress"><div></div></td>
            <td class="start"><button>Start</button></td>
        {{/if}}
        <td class="cancel"><button>Cancel</button></td>
    </tr>
</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out I was able to write the script in the Question to the page with appendTo() and preserve the ID and type meta data ..

the problem was whitespace and quotes I think.. when I got that part right the appendTo() worked and the other dependent include file worked too

Answer (score 2):

I don't know the templating engine behind what you are running, but have you looked at `.load()`? I have used that very successfully in a large project recently. The `.load()` function is a ajax shortcut that gets the result and appends it to an object in the DOM. http://api.jquery.com/load/

What kind of errors are you experiencing with inserting the code with the `.html()` function? As a side note, I assume you know about FireBug (http://getfirebug.com/)? That will help tremendously in troubleshooting these problems.

Thanks,

JMax

Comment: I like the idea of using .load() to grab the script instead of a jQuery insertion / append crowbar..  but its not clear to me how .load() preserves the script's ID , which I think is targeted by another script with a dependency on it.

Comment: I checked in FF and Chrome. I ran the `.load()` function to pull in the contents of `script.html`, and they both loaded into the DOM (FireBug, and Developer tools, respectively) with the ID intact. I'm not quite sure if you are asking for how the backend works?

Comment: There is another (include) script on this page that is dependent on the script I'm trying to write to page (load)... I think that dependent script needs to see the meta data of the script above, ie:

    **id="template-upload" type="text/x-jquery-tmpl"**

.. and I'm not sure how to get that meta data into the mix via the .load() method.

thanks